# How to use CountryCodePicker in RTL?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-experience

I'm using [CountryCodePickerProject](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject) in my project (awesome library). It allows to set a phone number prefix to the number. I wrote the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_phone_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_phone_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:tint="@color/lightGrayColor" />

    <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
        android:id="@+id/login_phone_ccp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:ccp_defaultNameCode="IL"
        app:ccp_autoDetectLanguage="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_phone_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Phone number"
        android:autofillHints="Phone number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It basically creates the following display:

> [icon] [Country Prefix] [Phone number box to fill]

In LTR language it looks great. But when I change the language of the phone to RTL it displays:

```
[Phone number box to fill] [Country Prefix] [icon]
```

It looks strange because the prefix should be on the left side of the phone number (even in RTL). Speaking of UI/UX thinking, what would be the best solution here to display RTL so it won't look awkward? Maybe force it to be on the left side? But then you will have something like: `+11 [________ملحوظة]`.

Comment: I think its better if you fork it and change it as per your needs

Comment: @AgentP I can play with it. My question is not how to do it, rather what is the best suited UX solution here.